# Как экранировать символ + в cmd файле

Tags: qt, cmd, bat

Пишу cmd скрипт для развёртывания Qt приложения (Winows 10). Для exe-шки нужна библиотека libstdc++-6.dll. Проблема в том, что команда `copy` не может найти файл, если в его имени есть символ +. Попробовал экранировать символом ^:

`copy %minGWdir%libstdc^+^+-6.dll %cd%\bin\`

Не работает во всяческих вариациях. Файлы без + в имени копируются нормально.

P.S. Утилита windeployqt эти библиотеки не копирует.

Comment: Квотируй так, как и любое другое длинное имя.

Comment: а пробовали copy "%minGWdir%libstdc++-6.dll %cd%\bin\"? То есть добавить кавычки двойные

Comment: Pr0gramm1st, да, ваш вариант сработал, но с учётом, что кавычки нужны только для первого аргумента "%minGWdir%libstdc++-6.dll" %cd%\bin\. Спасибо

Comment: А, да, ошибся...
"Минимум внимательности включено"